# Recommended way to read a file in Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

[Edited]

Let's say I have to read several text files and parse them line by line. This can be done in multiple ways. What is the best way? Would you recommend using java.util.Scanner or the new nio classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html
for this task? I am using Java JDK 7

Thank you all for answers. I have also found this useful [Fastest way of processing Java IO using ASCII lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111749/fastest-way-of-processing-java-io-using-ascii-lines)

Comment: If you just want to read all the content of a file then the `Files.readAllXxx` methods are quite convenient...

Comment: Best? Like "What is the best sort of ice cream"?

Comment: different file types require there own reading methods, some are for different purposes @tad

Comment: By best I meant - how would I make the decision to pick one of them. For example, if I want to read a text file line by line, I believe this can be achieved using either one of these classes.

Comment: That is a completely different question from the one you actually asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a file line by line there is no reason to go beyond `BufferedReader.readLine().` That being the only concrete question you've asked, that is the only concrete answer that can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) said, if you are using a JDK version less than 7, use a BufferedReader and use the second constructor signature in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) like so: `new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.ext"), 10000)`. With this you can further improve the performance of your app by adjusting the input buffer size in the constructor's second argument (e.g. 10000 bytes) as you see fit.

Comment: That buffer size argument is in chars, not bytes.

Comment: Then maybe you can use the Files.newBufferedReader() for moderate-sized files or Files.newByteChannel() for large files.